# Detecting both left and right mouse movement and no movement

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I'm trying to detect three mouse movement states in this (modified) [jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575951/jquery-mouse-direction-plugin) – left, right and stop (mouse not moving):

```
(function ($) {
    var options = {};
    var oldx = 0;
    var direction = "";
    $.mousedirection = function (opts) {
        var defaults = {};
        options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
            var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (e.pageX == oldx) {
                direction = "stop";
            } else if (e.pageX > oldx) {
                direction = "right";
            } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
                direction = "left";
            }
            $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
            $(activeElement).trigger({
                type: "mousedirection",
                direction: direction
            });
            oldx = e.pageX;
        });
    }
})(jQuery)

$(function () {
    $.mousedirection();
    $(".container").bind("mousedirection", function (e) {
        $(this).html("Mouse Direction: <b>" + e.direction + "</b>");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I believe there should be some kind of minimal delay between firing of subsequent checks in `mousemove` function but I'm not sure how to implement it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/7pBE7/1/ - mostly in 'stop' state, not detecting properly 'left' and 'right' mouse movement

Thanks a million.

Comment: how do you detect the mouse has stopped when you're using the trigger `mousemove`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7pBE7/3/ this is what i got using `setTimeout` after 1 second

Comment: Brilliant! I tried to include `setTimeout` but was doing it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Pedro's solution above, this answers my question:

```
(function ($) {
    var options = {};
    var oldx = 0;
    var direction = "";
    var stop_timeout = false;
    var stop_check_time = 150;
    $.mousedirection = function (opts) {
        var defaults = {};
        options = $.extend(defaults, opts);
        $(document).bind("mousemove", function (e) {
            var activeElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
            if (e.pageX > oldx) {
                direction = "right";
            } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
                direction = "left";
            }

            clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
            stop_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                direction = "stop";
                $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
                $(activeElement).trigger({
                    type: "mousedirection",
                    direction: direction
                });
            }, stop_check_time);

            $(activeElement).trigger(direction);
            $(activeElement).trigger({
                type: "mousedirection",
                direction: direction
            });
            oldx = e.pageX;
        });
    }
})(jQuery)

$(function () {
    $.mousedirection();
    $(".container").bind("mousedirection", function (e) {
        $(this).html("Mouse Direction: <b>" + e.direction + "</b>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fallenartist/7pBE7/5/

Comment: Great code! I made a fork where also up and down is determined.! https://jsfiddle.net/v0yjbj2y/