# How To Detect Mouse Move ONLY on Horizontal Move (To Left or to Right Move)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/zmwo1koh/) and let me know how I can detect the `mousemove()` ONLY when the mouse is moving to left or right?

Basically what is happening now is jquery detecting `mousemove` event even when the mouse is moving from top to down or down to top but I need to disable this and detect the mouse move event on moving Horizontally.

```js
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```

```css
#target{width:500px; height:120px; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  Move here
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: take a look to [detecting-both-left-and-right-mouse-movement-and-no-movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974178/detecting-both-left-and-right-mouse-movement-and-no-movement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Record the last position of the mouse and if the horizontal position has changed, run the code.

```js
var lastX = 0;

$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  if(lastX != event.pageX) {
    var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
    msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
    $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
  }
  lastX = event.pageX;
});
```

```css
#target{width:500px; height:120px; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  Move here
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```